# Strange behaviour using fgets and strtok_r

Tags: c, fgets, strtok

This is my code:

```
#define LEN 40
#define STUDLIST "./students.txt"

int main()
{
 FILE * studd;
 char del[] = "" " '\n'";
 char name[LEN], surname[LEN], str[LEN];
 char *ret;
 char *tokens[2] = {NULL};
 char *pToken = str;
 unsigned int i = 0;

 /* open file */
 if ( (studd = fopen(STUDLIST,"r") ) == NULL ) 
 {
   fprintf(stderr, "fopen\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 while((ret = fgets(str, LEN, studd)))
    {
     if(ret)
        {
         for( tokens[i] = strtok_r( str, del, &pToken ); ++i < 2; 
              tokens[i] = strtok_r( NULL, del, &pToken ) );

           strcpy(name, tokens[0]);
           strcpy(surname, tokens[1]);

           printf( "name = %s\n", name );
           printf( "surname = %s\n", surname );
         }
      fflush(studd);
    }
   fclose(studd);

 return 0;
}
```

Here there is the file students.txt: http://pastebin.com/wNpmXYis

I don't understand why the output isn't correct as I expected.
I use a loop to read each line with **fgets**, then I have a sting composed by **[Name Surname]**, and I want to divide it in two different strings (*[name]* and *[surname]*) using **strtok_r**. I tried with a static string and it works well, but If I read many strings from FILE the output is not correct as you can see here:

http://pastebin.com/70uPMzPh

Where is my fault?

Comment: I am not able to compile your code. Can you please show us the *correct* version?

Comment: There isn't a need for a loop if there are always just two strings.  i is 0 the first time, but you are also using tokens[1] even on the first run. The second time it is incremented to 2 and the loop condition fails.

Comment: @Grandaro: sorry! Now I edited in the right way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start **i** at zero:

```
unsigned int i = 0;
```

And later you increment it:

```
++i < 2;
```

You never set **i** back to zero, and in fact, continue incrementing **i** again for every new line in your file.  With 14 names in your input file, I expect **i** to get to about 14.
*(or maybe 13 or 15, depending on the exact logic)*.

So this line:

```
tokens[i] = strtok_r(...);
```

ends up putting **strtok** results into `tokens[2..15]`.  But only `tokens[0]` and `tokens[1]` are valid.  Everything else is ***undefined behavior***.

**Answer:**  Be sure you reset **i** to zero when you read a new line of your file.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using `for`loop?
...

```
while((ret = fgets(str, LEN, studd)))
{
  if(ret)
  {
    tokens[0] = strtok_r( str, del, &pToken );
    tokens[1] = strtok_r( NULL, del, &pToken );

    strcpy(name, tokens[0]);
    strcpy(surname, tokens[1]);

    printf( "name = %s\n", name );
    printf( "surname = %s\n", surname );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I don't have only one string to tokenize. I have many strings in a FILE. Where is the fgets to read strings from the FILE I have liked?